# Using ConcurrentHashMap to simulate the lock, is the impl OK safe?

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, concurrenthashmap

I read some interesting code from an open source project, and I don't understand it really.

The concurrentMapExample below is a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.
Can the code below prevent multiple threads return isLocked=true at the same time?

```
public boolean tryLock()
{
    isLocked = concurrentMapExample.putIfAbsent(key, "") == null;
    return isLocked;
}
```

Comment: Any feedback on my answer?  Remember to accept it if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

> Can the code below prevent multiple threads return isLocked=true at the same time?

Yes.  This code is thread-safe and only one thread will return null.  Other threads calling `putIfAbsent(...)` afterwards *with the same `key`* (!!) will get the `""` value and `isLocked` will be false.

To be pedantic, I would suggest that you wrap the equality check in a parens or maybe do something like the following to improve readability:

```
if (concurrentMapExample.putIfAbsent(key, "") == null)
   return true;
else
   return false;
```

This seems like an academic question but for posterity, there obviously are better wants to do this.  For example, the same logic using an `AtomicBoolean` would be:

```
private final AtomicBoolean isLocked = new AtomicBoolean(false);
...
return isLocked.compareAndSet(false, true);
```

Comment: Why would you do the `return true/return false` thing rather than just writing `return concurrentMapExample.putIfAbsent(key, "") == null`?  I can't imagine that having different semantics.

Comment: Because it reads better to me @LouisWasserman.  Anything that my brain has to stumble over (even for 3 seconds) isn't worth it IMHO.  It compiles down to the same code but it is more understandable.  It's the same reason why I don't write `while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)` type of code.

Comment: I agree that that `while` loop is difficult to read, but I guess we'll have to agree to disagree about the `putIfAbsent` case, which I find much more intuitive than the `if` version.

Comment: Because that concurrentmap is the cluster wide object, and the cluster itself gaurantee the thread safty.
So it is just a smart idea to impl the lock for cluster environment.                                                        >> This seems like an academic question but for posterity, there obviously are better wants to do this. For example, the same logic using an AtomicBoolean would be.

Comment: Ah.  Understood @huican.

Comment: I 100% agree with @LouisWasserman and withhold my upvote in solidarity. :-D